# Android Looper inside infinite loop

Tags: android

I have a thread with an infinite loop inside like the following

```
private Thread mThread = new Thread(){
    while(true){
        Looper.prepare();
        Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Looper.loop();
        Thread.sleep(15000); 
    }
};
```

I had the code without Looper.prepare and loop but it didn't compile. After adding the Looper code my thread gets executed one time. Of course I want the code to execute every 15 seconds. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: It wasn't clear sorry. I just want the code to keep executing every 15 seconds. Now that I added the Looper code it just runs one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(15000);` makes the execution bit slower so I will recommend you to use `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);`, it will optimize your code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            Looper.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Looper.loop(); 
        }
    }
}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

Declare a global variable for the handler like this:

```
Handler gHandler = new Handler();
```

Then declare a new thread:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000); 
                    gHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            // HERE WRITE YOUR CODE :)
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Although there are other solutions for this, but this is how I do it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is interesting. Any resources for other solutions. It looks like a hack.

Comment: This is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726055/android-loop-part-of-the-code-every-5-seconds

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me

```
private Thread mThread = new Thread(){
    Looper.prepare();
    while(true){
        Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Thread.sleep(15000); 
    }
};
```

For some reason it is not necesary to call `Looper.loop()`