# How to handle thread message every 3 seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am new to android and I am trying to build an app that reads speech signal values using a thread and display the value on the ui using  handler. [Recording thread that reads the values and sends message to handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X78Ua.jpg).[Handler for the recording thread message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ6Em.jpg)

I actually need the textview to update every 3 seconds , but the value of the variable value is getting updated very fast. In the code containing recording thread, I want to send the message after every 3 seconds(as can be seen, the while loop runs for 3 seconds). but I am unable to do that . Please help!!

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726055/android-loop-part-of-the-code-every-5-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Handler class:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // change your text here
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3*1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handler or TextView:

```
textView.postDelay(new Runnable());
```