# Why does timer loop not initialize at initial value when it calls onFinish() method?

Tags: android

I want to build a 5 second timer that counts down to 0 in 1 second intervils and then resets to the initial value of 5 seconds. The timer needs to run continously. After looking at this thread,
[Android - loop part of the code every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726055/android-loop-part-of-the-code-every-5-seconds?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I used the CountDownTimer Class and called the start() method within the onFinish() method so that when the timer finished, it would reset to 5. It does run on a continous loop, however I notice that after the first loop, it either countsdown as 4-3-2-1-0 or 5-3-2-1-0.
Can somebody explain to me why this happens?

```
private long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 5000;
//set up our variables
private CountDownTimer timer;
private TextView textView;
private Button starttimer;
private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    starttimer = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
    //set onclik listener when touch imput button
    starttimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            beginTime();
        }
    });
}

//creating my own method
private void beginTime() {

    timer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            start();
        }

    }.start();
}

private void updateCountDownText(){
    int minutes= (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000)/ 60;
    int seconds= (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    textView.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
        public void onFinish() {
          mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
   }
```

Comment: The code above didn't change anything.  I tried the code below and it displayed the initail value of 5 for a fraction of a second before counting down from 4
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
                updateCountDownText();
                start();
            }

Comment: oh! can you try adding a delay? for Countdown to begin?